# Create new variable that recognizes changes in a code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, match, cell

I have a `double matrix B` that has in `C1` the year 1998 and in `C2` a code (unrepeated). Each `C2` is given a value in `C3`.

```
%   C1      C2   C3
B=[ 1998    22   37 
1998    34    7
1998    76    12
1998    98    29
1998    107   14    
…]
```

This is how I got to `B`:

```
N1=[N{:,1} N{:,2} N{:,3}];
N1=unique(N1(:,1:3),'rows'); 
N3= unique(N1(:,1:2),'rows'); 
for m=1:size(N3,1)
    N3(m,3)=sum(N1(:,1) == N3(m,1) & N1(:,2)==N3(m,2));
end
B=N3((N3(:,1) == 1998),:);
```

I have a `cell-array A` with the years horizontally disposed in `R1`, un-repeated values in `Y`, and corresponding codes in the columns that follow. **The codes match the ones in `C2` from variable `B`.**

```
A={Y  1996 1997 1998 1999  %R1
1   107 107 22  22  
13  98  98  76  1267 
… }
```

Is there a way I could get a new variable that recognizes the change in the codes in variable `A`, and presents the corresponding values from `C3` in `B`? For instance:

```
AB={Y Initial C2 Change C2
1   107 14  22  37
13  98  29  76  12 }
```

Comment: Sorry forget my previous comment..., so in your variable A you want to find the codes that change between the years and then look them up in B to show the corresponding values?

Comment: @Yes. I want to look them up in B and get corresponding values (C3) both before and after the change.

Comment: I have a little bit hard to find out what you ask here, do you mean that you want to find the indices where `N1` change? There is a possibility to have more than 1 output in `unique`. the call `[a,b,c] = unique(M,'first')`, gives: `a` - the unique values in `M`, `b` - the indices where `a` occurs the first time in `M`, `c` - as `M=a(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
AB = {'Y' 'Initial' 'C2' 'Change' 'C2'}; % initialize result cell array

for i=2:size(A,1) % loop through rows of A

   indicesOfChanges = find(diff([A{i,2:end}])); % find changes in row

   for j=1:length(indicesOfChanges) % for all changes look up the corresponding values
       ind1=find(B(:,2)==A{i,indicesOfChanges(j)+1}); % row index in B of value before change
       ind2=find(B(:,2)==A{i,indicesOfChanges(j)+2}); % row index in B of value after change
       AB{end+1,1} = A{i,1};
       AB{end,2} = B(ind1,2);  
       AB{end,3} = B(ind1,3); 
       AB{end,4} = B(ind2,2); 
       AB{end,5} = B(ind2,3);
   end

end
```

Maybe this could be further improved by using a vectorized approach, but as long as your arrays aren't too big it should work fast enough using loops.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. The code is not working a 100%, because there's a problem w/ matrix dimensions, but I am going through it now. Thanks

Comment: Hi I fixed the code - as you said there were indexing issues. If you set up your data A and B like you described, it should get you AB.

Comment: I made some changes on my data (because it was slightly different from the example) and I tried your code, and the loop works for the first 9 rows and then gives the error 'matrix dimensions must agree. My double matrix B 321 rows while my cell array A has 4000 rows. Do you think is because of that? Thank you.

Comment: It should work for any number of rows. I assumed that all possible codes in A are all stored in B. If not, then find(...) does not return anything and you get an error. I think this might be the case here.

Comment: I am almost sure it is that. Thanks!